# Replace substring in an string without using the replace method

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function which replaces a substring for another one in a given string (without using the method replace).

I obtain `"AAew AAews"` instead of `"AAw AAws"`

```
def replace_substring(string1,substring,replace):
    new=""
    if substring in string1:
        for i in range(0,len(string1)):
            if string1[i:i+len(substring)]==substring:
                new=new+replace
            else:
                new=new+string1[i]
    return new
print(replace_substring("New News","Ne","AA"))
```

Comment: after `new=new+replace` you continue the loop from the next char. You need to skip `len(substring)` characters.

Comment: Write down your example and algorithm on paper step by step. What issues do you find?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip an iteration by the length of the string you are replacing by minus the character you already replaced after you do your replacement.

From your output I can see that you are replacing the first character, and after replacement the loop checks the second character, which was part of the string to be replaced. But because `e` is now not one of the replacement string to look out for, it adds it to the new string.

This is a bit messy but I just changed a bit of your code and it works. Your code is using a for loop, so to skip a loop you will have to create flags and set multiple conditions.

The simpler way would be to use a while loop where you can skip the loop based on a simpler condition.

I have included a while loop example at the bottom, it's shorter and easier to understand and manipulate for your case.

You can compare both implementation and see what I mean.

```
def replace_substring(string1,substring,replace):
    new=""
    skip = 0 # flag to know when a replacement was made therefore skip
    skiptimes = len(replace) -1 #number of times to skip -1 for the first replacement

    if substring in string1:
        for i in range(0,len(string1)):
            if skiptimes > 0 and skip == 1: # skip only trigger if flagged and number of skips which is the length of the replacement string is left
                skiptimes -= 1
                if skiptimes == 0:
                    skip = 0 # change skip flag back to 0 once skips length of replacement string is done
                    skiptimes = len(replace) -1 #reset the length of replacement
                continue
            else: # if no flags just run the code as per normal no skips.
                if string1[i:i+len(substring)]==substring:
                    new=new+replace
                    skip = 1
                else:
                    new=new+string1[i]
            
    return new
print(replace_substring("New News","Ne","AA"))
```

My output is,

```
'AAw AAws'
```

This is a while loop example as you can see it is much shorter and easier to skip loops.

```
def replace_substring(string1,substring,replace):
    new=""
    if substring in string1:
        counter = len(string1)
        i = 0 #start at index 0
        while i != len(string1): # as long as not length of string, keep running loop
            if string1[i:i+len(substring)]==substring:
                new=new+replace
                i += len(replace) - 1 # skip the length of the replace minus the one already replaced
            else:
                new=new+string1[i]
            i += 1 # add 1 to move to the next index
    return new
print(replace_substring("New News","Ne","AA"))
```

My output also is,

```
'AAw AAws'
```

Next time if you are not sure of what the problem is, print the `new` or item at the end of every loop instead of just the end of the program. You will see how the program is working and where the bug is. You can also use the debug tool in most ide like pycharm and vscode to help you see the output at the end of every loop.